# Nested schema replacement in Angular-fullstack

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I use Angular-Fullstack for a little Pomodoro WebApp. I have a problem when I want to add a comment a Pomodoro.

Here is my model :

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
var UserSchema = require('mongoose').model('User').schema;

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String
});

var PomodoroSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  ended: Boolean,
  comments: [CommentSchema],
  user: UserSchema
});

export default mongoose.model('Pomodoro', PomodoroSchema);
```

And here is my problem:

- I create a pomodoro : OK
- I add a comment : OK
- I add another comment : The answer is the first comment 2 times

Here are some screenshots:

- The creation of the pomodoro

  - What is send
    [image: What is send]
  - What is received
    [image: What is received]
- The creation of the first comment

  - What is send
    [image: What is send]
  - What is received
    [image: What is received]
- The creation of the second comment

  - What is send
    [image: What is send]
  - What is received
    [image: What is received]